# replace the capture group in groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

I am new to groovy and have been trying this

My target string can begin with **where** or **there** and can be followed by **any number of .(dot character) and a word**. I need to replace all the **.(Dot characters) with _ (underscore)**

Anything that does **not begin with *where* or *there* should not be replaced**

The sample String is

```
    hey where.is.the book on.brown.table 
    hey there.is.a.boy.in.the city Delhi
    hey here.is.the.boy living next door
```

The Expected output is

```
    hey where_is_the book on.brown.table 
    hey there_is_a_boy_in_the city Delhi
    hey here.is.the.boy living next door
```

I am able to match the exact pattern. With `/(where|there)\.((\w+)(\.))+/`, but when I use the `replaceAll` I end up with incorrect results.

Comment: I am able to match the exact pattern. With  /(where|there)\.((\w+)(\.))+/ But when I use the replaceAll I end up with incorrect results. I tried using capture group to retain the required part of string but the number of dots are not consistent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
/(\G(?!\A)\w+|\b(?:where|there)\b)\./
```

Or if you need to only handle these 2 words:

```
/(\G(?!\A)\w+|\b[wt]here\b)\./
```

Replace with `$1_`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1cOWmv/1).

**Details**

- `(\G(?!\A)\w+|\b(?:where|there)\b)` - Group 1 that captures:

  - `\G(?!\A)\w+|` - the end of the previous match (`\G(?!\A)`) and then 1+ word chars (`\w+`), or
  - `\b(?:where|there)\b` - either a `where` or `there` whole word (you may even write it as `\b[tw]here\b` if you only need to handle these 2 words)
- `\.` - a dot.

See the [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/MebBAn):

```
String s = "hey where.is.the book on.brown.table\nhey there.is.a.boy.in.the city Delhi\nhey here.is.the.boy living next door"
print s.replaceAll(/(\G(?!\A)\w+|\b(?:where|there)\b)\./, '$1_')
```

Output:

```
hey where_is_the book on.brown.table
hey there_is_a_boy_in_the city Delhi
hey here.is.the.boy living next door
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Wiktor, it worked like a charm. It was a difficult expression for me indeed. Thank you for explaining in detail. I also went through the common regex issues. It was enlightening.